# Error W005 URL namespace isn't unique

Tags: django

'Copied this code from the Django tutorial into my app's urls.py file...

```
from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'polls'
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index, name='index'),
    path('<int:question_id>/', views.detail, name='detail'),
    path('<int:question_id>/results/', views.results, name='results'),
    path('<int:question_id>/vote/', views.vote, name='vote'),
]
```

When I start my server it produces the following error...

> (urls.W005) URL namespace 'polls' isn't unique. You may not be able
>   to reverse all URLs in this namespace

I've tried using some other name besides 'polls' but with the same result.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Check your root urls file, and be sure to have unique name:
(django 2+)

For example:

mysite/urls.py
-->

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import include, path

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include('polls.urls')),      #polls.urls is unique
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),      #admin.site.urls is unique
]
```

Answer (score -1):

```
from django.conf.urls import url
import views


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index,name='index'), 
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9a-f-]+)/$',views.detail,name='detail'),
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9a-f-]+)/results/$',views.results,name='results'),
    url(r'^(?P<question_id>[0-9a-f-]+)/vote/$',views.vote,name='vote'),
]
```

Write your url file like shown above.

Comment: Thanks so much for the reply, but I'm trying to use Django 2.0.2.  The app_name = 'polls' is an attempt to use namespacing.  My code works without the namespacing line, but not with.  This offered code appears to be for an earlier Django version.  'Tried it just for fun but got a slew of errors.